# RecycleView error: items are being duplicated, how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have programmed a recycler view in my android studio project. When  I click in one of the items of this recycle View a new fragment is opened, thought when I return to recycler view screen the items of the recycle view are duplicated, what can I do so that not occurs ?

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_config, container, false);
        final Context context = view.getContext();

        recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerConfig);
        this.adicionarConfig();

        adapterMain adapter = new adapterMain( listaConfig );

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
          new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                  context, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                      if(position == 0){
                      FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                      fr.replace(R.id.frameA, new configContaFragment());
                      fr.addToBackStack(null).commit();

                  }
                  if(position == 1){
                      FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                      fr.replace(R.id.frameA, new configLayoutFragment());
                      fr.addToBackStack(null).commit();

                  }
                  if(position == 2){
                      FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                      fr.replace(R.id.frameA, new configNotificacoesFragment());
                      fr.addToBackStack(null).commit();
                  }
                  if(position == 3){
                      FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                      fr.replace(R.id.frameA, new sobreFragment());
                      fr.addToBackStack(null).commit();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              }
          }
          )
        );

    return view;
    }

    public void adicionarConfig(){

        Configuracoes config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_secure , "Conta", "Informações, Sala, Escola");
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

        config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_config , "Layout", "Cor de fundo, Estilos, Propriedades");
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

        config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_notification , "Notificação", "Tipo de notificação, ");
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

        config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_about , "Sobre nós", null);
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

    }
```

Adapter class code is as below

```
public class adapterMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterMain.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Configuracoes> listaConfig;

    public adapterMain(List<Configuracoes> lista) {
        this.listaConfig = lista;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View listaMain = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_main, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(listaMain);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        Configuracoes config = listaConfig.get(i);
        myViewHolder.imagem.setImageResource(config.getImagem());
        myViewHolder.nome.setText(config.getNome());
        myViewHolder.conteudo.setText(config.getConteudo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaConfig.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imagem;
        TextView nome, conteudo;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imagem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcone);
            nome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
            conteudo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the full code of the fragment

Comment: can you try with only defining adapter in onCreateView() but declare it outside onCreateView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `adicionarConfig` method as

```
public void adicionarConfig(){
        if(this.listaConfig != null) {
           this.listaConfig.clear();
        }
        Configuracoes config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_secure , "Conta", "Informações, Sala, Escola");
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

        config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_config , "Layout", "Cor de fundo, Estilos, Propriedades");
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

        config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_notification , "Notificação", "Tipo de notificação, ");
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

        config = new Configuracoes( R.mipmap.ic_about , "Sobre nós", null);
        this.listaConfig.add(config);

    }
```